# algorithm - Path finding given vertex constraints

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory

I'm going to give the general case of this problem, because this is the 2nd time I've seen something that can be reduced to this and I haven't been able to find anything better than checking every path.

Suppose we have a directed graph G with vertices V such that there are no cycles and no self-edges. Additionally, each vertex has a color. Find the longest path starting from a given vertex such that the path goes through at most 1 vertex of each color.

I've implemented what is essentially depth-first search by removing all vertices of the added vertex's color in the recursive step, and I'm wondering if there's a better way to do it. The issue I keep running into is that storing past results is difficult because of the color restriction, so shortest path algorithms like Dijkstra's don't give the right result.

Comment: I can come up with `O(n*2^k)` algorithm where `n = max { |E|, |V|}` and `k = #colors`. Note that this problem is very different from shortest path, because in here you are talking about longest path (which is generally NP-Hard problem, but the graph is a DAG, so there might be efficient solutions).

Comment: Backtracking (DFS) sounds good. There is no need to store past states, just colours that are visited with a current branch. Colour and vertex ordering is needed for a backtrecking, to know visit order from a current vertex. Solution is found when current branch has number of colours length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to you problem is **No**.

If you assign each vertex with distinct color, your problem will be reduced to [Hamiltonian path problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path) which is NP-hard.

Comment: That makes sense. For the record, what I ended up doing was depth first search with a globally updated top score and a upper-bound function to avoid traversing some nodes. It didn't improve time complexity, but in practice it was around 3x as fast.